# gRPC basic Authentication in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, grpc

New in gRpc here. I tried to search for an example of Basic Authentication in C# but I couldn't find. I found only one regarding Go in the link above:
https://tillknuesting.medium.com/grpc-http-basic-auth-oauth2-bearer-tokens-f088b5a2314
Can anyone help how to implement it in C#?

Comment: One of the easiest ways to implement authentication would probably be JWT tokens. Check the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: For the moment I have only basic authentication as an option. Later on we will implement JWT probably.

Answer (score 0):

[Securing gRPC-based Microservices in .NET Core](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-grpc-microservices-dotnet-core/) is a pretty good introduction to implementing authentication and authorization. It focuses on using Auth0, but concepts can be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var channelOptions = new GrpcChannelOptions
{
    Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Ssl,
    HttpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        DefaultRequestHeaders =
        {
            // Replace "YOUR_TOKEN" with the actual bearer token
            { "Authorization", "Bearer YOUR_TOKEN" }
        }
    }
};

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://your.grpc.server.address", channelOptions);
```